# Extend SQL query to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query returns Code, Designation, Standard and Quantity from Table_621 which are not existing in table Components.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code
    ,a.Designation
    ,a.Standard
    ,a.Quantity
FROM Table_621 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Components 
                  WHERE Components.Code = a.Code)
```

I need, within the same query, to select also in other tables: Table_333, Table_853 and so on.
How can I expand the above query to select from more tables?

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL`. Like `SELECT <...> FROM Table_621 <...> UNION ALL SELECT <...> FROM Table_333 <...> UNION ALL SELECT <...> FROM Table_853 <...>`

Comment: just join to these other tables or Union all with these other tables, and keep this same `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm really hoping the table names are just an attempt to anonymize the question, and you don't actually have a table called Table_853!

Comment: @IMSoP, lol. Just testing using names that make sense at this stage.

Comment: @Notulysses, mhmmm....Not really clear to me. Could you show me in ananswer how to achieve this.

Comment: @IMSoP once I have worked on a database where all the tables where named like this tbl_123 , tbl_456 and to top it all the column names where tbl_123_1, tbl_123_2,tbl_123_3 , and I was given a big fat manual to check exactly explaining what information was held in what table and what column. And there were nearly 1300 tables and some tables with over 70-80 columns, In them days I hated going to work every day lol

Comment: @M.Ali I think if I was faced with that I would either a) resign, or b) write a script to process the manual into DDL statements: `CREATE VIEW users AS SELECT tbl_123_1 as user_name, tbl_123_2 as password_hash, tbl_123_3 as email_address FROM tbl_123` :P

Comment: @IMSoP I am talking about nearly 1300 tables and over 5000 stored procedures :) and I wasnt allowed to change the schema as "Application would break". lool

Comment: @M.Ali Hence the need to process the manual, not write the views by hand. The script could then also output a `sed` script to make human-readable versions of the stored procedures by substituting in the view names wherever the table names appeared. Might take a while to get it right, but that sounds a lot more fun than learning to maintain the code without it... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Designation, a.Standard, a.Quantity FROM Table_621 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Designation, a.Standard, a.Quantity FROM Table_333 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Designation, a.Standard, a.Quantity FROM Table_853 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
```